# Converting an extended JSON document to mongo shell format

Tags: json, mongodb, mongo-shell

MongoDB can output data in [Extended JSON format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).  For example, in relaxed mode, a date is represented as:

```json
{"my_date_field": {"$date": "2000-01-23T01:23:45.678+00:00"}}
```

But, to my knowledge, the legacy `mongo` shell cannot parse extended JSON, supporting a [different format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/) instead:

```json
{"my_date_field": ISODate("2000-01-23T01:23:45.678+00:00")}
```

Is there a CLI app to convert from extended JSON to mongo shell format?  Or is it possible to parse extended JSON from the legacy `mongo` shell?  (I'm aware that `mongoimport` and the newer `mongosh` already support extended JSON natively.)

Comment: Are you lookinng for https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/bson/extended-json/

Comment: What are you trying to do? The extended json is for mongoimport/export tools. Shell is an interactive shell. I would restore the json file to the database, then connect to the db from the shell and work with the data.

Comment: @AlexBlex I want to store documents in a JSON format comaptible with regular JSON tools, but use that same document in queries from `mongo` shell

Comment: Still doesn't make much sense to me. Extended JSON is used to store documents outside of mongodb. mongo shell is an interactive javascript shell. It uses javascript objects (not json) to query documents from the database. e.g. ISODate you mentioned is not format but a helper function that returns a javascript Date object. The shell then converts it to BSON value of type 9 and sends it as a part of the query to the database.  You can see the source code of this function if you type `print(ISODate)`  in the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the legacy (aka deprecated) mongo shell does not support extended JSON parsing.  However, the new mongosh shell provides the EJSON class for exactly that.